# Attach multiple bash prompts to the same docker session

Tags: docker

I am running various servers on a docker container and want to open up editors and tail outputs etc.  How can that be done (to the *same* container - not a new copy of the original docker image) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly to `starting` a docker container: but instead of `run` it is `exec`

```
docker exec -it 4bb8e8186a98 bin/bash
```